# Amazon SNS to SQS - confirming subscription using .NET SDK

Tags: .net, amazon-sqs, amazon-ses, amazon-sns, aws-sdk

I'm trying to setup Amazon Ses notifications to go to my SQS Queue. 
I'm following instructions how to create SQS queue, then SNS topic, and subscribe one to the other.

However in the management console the subscriptions come up "Pending Confirmation".

I'm using the .NET AWS SDK, how can Confirm the subscription? Or even better, why do I have to confirm? The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToSQS.html#SendMessageToSQS.sqs.permissions) says

> If the owner of the queue creates the subscription, the subscription
>   is automatically confirmed and the subscription should be active
>   almost immediately.

I'm using my AWS credentials for all the API calls as owner so I dont see why I need to confirm but how can I anyways?

```
    private static string CreateBounceTopicAndQueue(IAmazonSQS sqsClient, IAmazonSimpleNotificationService snsClient)
    {
        // 1. Create an Amazon SQS queue named ses-bounces-queue.
        CreateQueueResponse createQueueResponse = sqsClient.CreateQueue(new CreateQueueRequest()
        {
            QueueName = AppGlobal.SesBouncesQueue,
            Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                { "ReceiveMessageWaitTimeSeconds", "20" }
            }
        });
        string queueUrl = createQueueResponse.QueueUrl;

        // 2. Create an Amazon SNS topic named ses-bounces-topic
        CreateTopicResponse createTopicResponse = snsClient.CreateTopic(new CreateTopicRequest
        {
            Name = AppGlobal.SesBouncesTopic
        });
        string topicArn = createTopicResponse.TopicArn;

        // 3. Configure the Amazon SNS topic to publish to the SQS queue
        var response =  snsClient.Subscribe(new SubscribeRequest
        {
            TopicArn = topicArn,
            Endpoint = queueUrl,
            Protocol = "https"
        });

        return queueUrl;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't subscribe an SQS queue to an SNS topic by creating an https subscription with the queue URL.

You create an "**sqs**" (not https) protocol subscription with the queue's **[ARN](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html)** (not web endpoint) as the endpoint.

---

```
protocol
Type: System.String
The protocol you want to use. 
...
sqs -- delivery of JSON-encoded message to an Amazon SQS queue
```

---

```
endpoint
Type: System.String
The endpoint that you want to receive notifications. Endpoints vary by protocol...

For the sqs protocol, the endpoint is the ARN of an Amazon SQS queue
```

---

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/items/MSNS_SNSSubscribe_String_String_StringNET4_5.html

Comment: does not clear up anything and thanks for documentation homepage as if I didnt know it's there, I did link to it myself didnt I?

Comment: @parliament, I imagine it must have been annoying that it seemed like I assumed you didn't know where the docs were, or didn't bother looking.  I didn't intend to paste the main page link.  When I copy/pasted that URL, I was on my android, and didn't notice that the URL on the docs site, annoyingly, doesn't change as you navigate through it.  The correct URL and some citations from it have been added to the updated answer, which I believe you will see to have been correct... SNS to SQS requires the protocol to be "sqs" (not https) and the endpoint to be the queue's ARN, not URL.

Comment: thank you very much for the correction. will try soon.

Comment: yup that was it, thanks again. for future stumblers using SES when calling sesClient.SetIdentityNotificationTopic() "SnsTopic" in the request is also the Topic ARN.